# How to import kitty.sav from kitty executable

Tags: windows, ssh, telnet

I use kitty for telnet/ssh from windows.
I have recently copied "kitty.sav" from one laptop to other.

It would be very helpful if someone guide how to import this file so that I can get all saved sessions.

Answer (score 0):

rename the .sav file to .reg, double click and be happy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).